# friendly_id and finding records by params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am going to use friendly_if gem for pretty urls. I am able to get the nice looking urls. However, I all the code in the controller was getting records by id. like so:

```
@image = Image.find(params[:id])
```

Do I need to start finding records by name now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Image.friendly.find(params[:id])
```